# What is known of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n/n^n$?

Tags: limits, functions

What is $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\,-\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n^n}$$?

What is known about specific values of this function at say $-2,-1,0,1,2,3$?

Comment: For any $x$, the value of the infinite sum is bounded below by $x$. Therefore, as $x$ goes to infinity, so does the sum. EDIT: this reasoning doesn't work if $x$ goes to negative infinity

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee I think it's a bit more subtle, as the limit in question is as $x$ goes to minus infinity

Comment: @ThomasGrubb missed the minus sign! thanks

Comment: @ChargeShivers I assume the OP wants to know the values of the series for $x=-2,-1,0,1,2,3$, in addition to asking about the limit.

Comment: The function defined by a series :$\quad f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n/n^n\quad$ cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary function. A closed form requires the definition of a special function. 

https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function

Comment: $
\begin{array}{rr}
x&series\\
\hline
 -100 & -15591. \\
 -90 & -1788.02 \\
 -80 & -153.477 \\
 -70 & -10.0578 \\
 -60 & -1.52138 \\
 -50 & -1.23071 \\
 -40 & -1.24498 \\
 -30 & -1.27736 \\
 -20 & -1.34755 \\
 -10 & -1.56863 \\
 0 & 0. \\
 10 & 186.725 \\
 20 & 10594.9 \\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401734), several users proved that

$$ \lim_{x\to-\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k^k} = -1. $$

A slight generalization is also possible: In [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403478/what-is-the-answer-to-this-limit/403578#403578), I proved that

$$ \lim_{x\to-\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k^{k-m}} = \begin{cases} -1, & m = 0 \\ 0, & m = 1, 2, \cdots \end{cases} $$

---

On the other hand, I am not sure if any non-trivial special values for this power series is known. Although I am quite skeptical, one might benefit from the following integral representation

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k^k} = \int_{0}^{1} x \cdot u^{-xu} \, du $$

which is a generalization of the [*Sophomore's dream*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).