# Find monotonic functions going from $0$ to $+\infty$ for $x \in (-\infty,+\infty)$ (similar to $e^x$)

Tags: functions, exponential-function, special-functions

How can we find functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with exponential-like properties, namely:

- $f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable;
- $f(x)$ and all its derivatives are monotonic;
- $f(x)$ and all its derivatives obey the following limits:

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=0$$

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$$

---

One such function is obviously the exponent itself ($a,b$ - real positive constants):

$$f(x)=ae^{bx}$$

Another function which seems to have these properties (I don't know how to prove it) is the 'Sophomore's function':

$$s(x)=\int_0^1 u^{-u~x} du=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k-1}}{k^k}$$

For the proof of the integral formula see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/401816/269624) by Sangchul Lee.

The derivatives are easy to find (both for the series and the integral formula) and they all seem to obey the above properties:

[image]

---

> How can we find other such functions?
>
> And (related) how to prove that $s(x)$ has these properties?

Comment: I think a nice restriction to the problem would be to only look for analytic functions.  Then you could try to characterize these functions by their power series coefficients.

Comment: @mathematician, could you provide an example of an infinitely differentiable function which is not analytic?

Comment: The classic example is the function $f$ defined by $f(x) = exp(-1/x^2)$ for $x > 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If $g(x) \ge 0$,
$\lim_{x \to -\infty} g(x) = 0$,
and
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t) dt
= \infty
$,
then
$f(x)
=\int_{-\infty}^x g(t) dt
$
is such a function.

(added a bit later)

If you want
all the derivatives
to be monotonic,
impose that restriction
on $g$.

Comment: I really think the condition $g(x) \geq 0$ should be clarified. Otherwise, $g(x)=C$ fits the first two conditions for any $C \geq 0$, but $f(x)$ doesn't work the way it should

Comment: Otherwise, a good suggestion, but you could at least offer some explicit $g(x)$

Comment: I added the condition $\lim_{x \to -\infty} g(x) = 0$.

Comment: Any example of g(x)? Or what about my second question?